# why vim see few files as arguments to CCTreeLoadXRefDBFromDisk

Tags: vim

```
autocmd VimEnter * if filereadable('cctree.out') | CCTreeLoadXRefDBFromDisk cctree.out | endif
```

I receive error message:

```
E172: Only one file name allowed:  CCTreeLoadXRefDBFromDisk cctree.out | endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this command treats `|` as a part of its argument (it is the default unless one specified `-bar` when defining command. Yet another weird default). Try

```
function s:TreeLoad(file)
    if filereadable(a:file)
        execute 'CCTreeLoadXRefDBFromDisk' fnameescape(a:file)
    endif
endfunction
augroup VimrcTreeLoad
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * :call s:TreeLoad('cctree.out')
augroup END
```